# Problem with vertex paint to .fbx

Tags: modeling, texturing, export, vertex-groups

I have been trying to export a model with vertex colors, from a blender model to FBX.
(And then to Roblox)
So I found out (export with vertex colors property) 
But, I cant seem to find the export with vertex colors in the FBX export dialog.

[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/90747/67923texture) person said that there was a property, but I cant find it.

> If you want to use simple colors instead of textures, you can use
>   Vertex Paint mode and color your model using this method. Roblox can
>   import vertex colors contained in your model (if not, make sure you
>   have ticked export vertex colors in the FBX/OBJ exporter dialog in
>   Blender).

Please see picture;
[image]

Comment: The fact that no one is answering doesn't mean you need to post another question. It's not how things work on this site. As to the question - did you actually try to export colors via FBX? I see no problem in exporting them, if tthere aren't any options export without options and see how it works. In general FBX supports vertex colors

Comment: @MrZak, sorry! But I was impatient. Yeah, I tried to export, and the colors did not come up. I wonder what it is...

Comment: @MrZak, I tried with a few other models. All of them went either Solid Brown or Solid Red....

Comment: @MrZak, please help, this is very important for my upcoming game.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos maybe you can help? Please read the other comments thanks.

Comment: Make sure to check import settings of FBX in your end application. From what I tried FBX supports vertex paint without checking any additional options, you just need to export mesh geometry, vertex colors will be exported via FBX. Some programs can require UV map for further import, try to unwrap and export. Anyway this question seems to be about import problems of 3-rd party application rather than export problems of Blender.

Comment: @MrZak, I am fairly new to blender, so I do not know what UV mapping is or how to do it. Is it a kind of making a texture out of a vertex color??

Comment: No it isn't. UV unwrapping is process of unfolding mesh. I'd advise to go through tutorials, here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important/38653 is introduction on UV map. Generally vertex colors will be exported out of Blender without any additional actions, my point was that it could depend on requirements of the end application